# How to replace text in message with regex with variable get in sheet in google apps script

Tags: regex, google-apps-script

Firstly, I'm using google apps script 
I get an text body and I want to replace placeholder with variables in a sheet, I get a variable in my sheet and i want to replace it with regex but it's not working

it's working with a variable that i just set but not with an value that i get in a sheet... I don't know why...

````
function replaceInBody() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var lastLigne = sheet.getLastRow()
  var lastColumn = sheet.getLastColumn()
  var firstLigne = sheet.getRange(1,1,1,lastColumn).getValues();
  var newBody
  Logger.log('firstLigne: %s', firstLigne)

  var data
  var bodyTest = 'blablabla {name} blablabla {var1} blabla'
  Logger.log('bodyTest: %s', bodyTest)
  var notwork = firstLigne[0][2] 
  var work = 'name'
  Logger.log('notwork: %s', notwork) // finally it's work by rewriter the code 
  Logger.log('work: %s', work)

  Logger.log('**')
  Logger.log(new RegExp("{"+ work +"}", 'g'))
  newBody = bodyTest.replace(new RegExp("{"+ notwork +"}", 'g'), 'changed')
  Logger.log('newBody: %s', newBody)
  newBody = bodyTest.replace(new RegExp("{"+ work +"}", 'g'), 'changed')
  Logger.log('newBody: %s', newBody)

}
```
just my text is not change with notwork variable but it's the same variable... // finally it's work by rewriter the code but I don't know my first mistake thanks to all of you :p
````

Comment: Please, note that we can't help you in debugging the issue unless you provide us with the rest of the code needed to reproduce it. For example, it might be related to what is written into `getvalue` variable

Comment: Show Logs of `Logger.log('No: %s', No)
Logger.log('yes: %s', yes)`

Comment: By rewriting it to simplify my problem the part that did not work is finally functional! I am sorry for the time you have spent! Neverveless, you have helped me a lot, thank you all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change your `replace()` method to:

```js
var regex1 = 'blablabla {name} blablabla {name} blabla';
console.log(regex1.replace(/name/g, 'Changed'));
```

This will find every appearance of "name" and change it. You can take a look at [the method's documentation](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp) to see how to work with these more simply.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I would like to add a variable in the replace method... and if try with `bodyTest.replace(new RegExp(No, 'g'), 'changed')` if the same result it's not working but with the 'yes' variable it's working, I think the problem it's the method for get the value on the sheet but i can't solve it ...

Comment: By rewriting it to simplify my problem the part that did not work is finally functional! I am sorry for the time you have spent! Neverveless, you have helped me a lot, thank you guy !